# Best authentication for modular Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rails-engines, subproject

I'm still learning Rails, but faced with this project: Web solution should consist of three parts - the website, section for partners and admin panel. Section for partners and admin panel should be available as subdirectories (customer's requirement) like this:

```
somesite.com
somesite.com/partners/
somesite.com/admin/
```

I decided to make three separate applications with common models and business logic and deploy them in mentioned way using Passenger and Apache.

In the database should be two models: `Admin` (for administrators only) and `User` (quite fat model, common for users and partners, differs by `is_partner` field). Because those models are common to all three sites, I decided to put them in the Rails Engine, and then use appropriate model for each application. But now I have the issue of choosing the suitable authentication module.

Could you advice one? Should I try to use some already existing solution or I better have to implement my own authentication? Or may be my entire approach to this project is wrong from beginning?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use one `User` model, since you won't need to duplicate any logic, and use three roles: user, partner, and admin, unless admins are drastically different from other users. For authentication, I would suggest [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), which is the go-to authentication system for Rails. For authorization, I would suggest [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

If you're looking for a pre-made admin interface, try [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) or [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin). RailsAdmin is simple to use and easily configurable, but not too customizable, while ActiveAdmin is a little more difficult to use but more customizable. Both of them are integrated with devise.

Comment: User and Admin are completely different models, so authentication module should use models from rails engine, but have separate configurations for each application.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not use RailsAdmin or something similar, because "admin" interface - it's actually a full-featured web-application with a quite specific logic.